# Are these two sets uncountable or countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$\{x \in (0,1) \, | \, x = 0.a_1a_2...a_n... \text{ where each } a_i = 0 \text{ or } 1 \text{ and only finitely many } a_i = 0 \}$

$\{x \in (0,1) \, | \, x = 0.a_1a_2...a_n... \text{ where } 0 \leq a_i \leq 9 \text{ and only finitely many } a_i = 0  \}$

I feel that they are both countable. But I can't get any idea to prove...

Comment: Please use latex.

Comment: HINT : In the first case, can you see that the decimal expansion is eventually $11111...$? In that case, what can you say about $x$? But in the second case, you cannot predict what number comes once all the zeros are gone, so this is likely to be uncountable.

Comment: It's subtle but in the first you have only one option (and no choice) for the terms that are not 0.  In the second you have 9 options (and thus choice) for the terms that are not 0.  Lack of choice vs. choice makes *all* the difference.

Comment: @Gal: These set theory tags are meant to be disjoint. Please read the description that many people have put a lot of time into before retagging.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  The difference is that you have infinitely many choices between $1$ and $2$ in the second case.  You can make a bijection between the expansions that have only $1$s and $2$s and the binary numbers in $(0,1)$.